# Tag <a> lose its background after page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to assign a background to my  elements with javascript, but the tags keep the background only during the page reloading, for then switching back to their normal background. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".container_menu ul li a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Css:

```
.container_menu ul li a.active{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.156863);
}
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="" href="user">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/about">About the autor</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/login">Manage</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does you mean by "*but the tags keep the background only during the page reloading, for then switching back to their normal background*"? Did you mean when you click on `<a>` the background changes, but when page load successful it returns to normal?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The time you can see the background is only before the page reloads, it lasts for an half second or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is altering the page after it has been loaded. So when you reload the page, it goes back to its initial state.

What you are trying to do is hardly achievable without some server side code (unless you are building a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) but I don't think so). Your server needs to know what is the active page so it renders it with your link having the `active` class.

If you can't or do not want to deal with the server solution, you'll have to find out what is the active page in your javascript code. It means that you'll need to detect it and then add the class to the proper element. This operation can take time (i.e while the javascript file loads) and the link might first appears without its active state for a short period. Anyway, here is a possible way to detect the active page:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link-user-about');
if (/user\/about\/$/.test(window.location.href)) {
    link.className = 'active';
}
```

**Note:** this is not the complete solution but a good hint ;)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. My website is entirely made up in php, and right now i'm trying hard to understand your answer, because i think I'm missing some theory here

Comment: Thank you very very much for explaining me this in a way that probably i wouldn't ever come up with.
I've made a couple of changes at my php code and made up to have the effect i needed. I honestly didn't know i had to make it through some server side programming language's work arounds. I thought it would have been easy and fluent to make it via javascript or css. Anyway it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using .active which means that the background will only be applicable while it is active.
https://jsfiddle.net/1p5zzwrf/1/

```
.container_menu ul li a.active{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.156863);
}

.container_menu ul li a{
    background-color: rgba(255, 111, 255, 0.156863);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually trying to have the effect to change the background when you select a link from the list, and then keeping it until you switch to another link. In order to show to the user the state of where he is browsing in that moment.

Comment: Use a:active class instead of doing it with JS. Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the user where he's browsing at the moment you first have to set `active` class on the link.

So to do that:

`index.html`

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="user">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/about">About the autor</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/login">Manage</a></li>
</ul>
```

`gallery.html`

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="" href="user">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="user/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/about">About the autor</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="user/login">Manage</a></li>
</ul>
```

And so on.

If you got a server scripting language that would make it easier for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes i know i have to do it that way, but it's not working apparently. I'm using jquery functions in order to achieve it, but my <a> tags are not keeping the class value. I've post the jquery code in my post.

Comment: not keeping the class value even without doing anything after page reload?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I think the correct solution is from @Gabin anyway
Thanks!